# Django model is saving twice with image resize

Tags: django

I am trying to resize images before upload using the following code. However, I get two saved models after submitting the form when I apply the custom `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):` function. Why is that?

```
class Players(models.Model):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', default="default.jpg", null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        img_read = storage.open(self.player_img.name, 'rb')
        img = Image.open(img_read)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            in_mem_file = io.BytesIO()
            img.convert('RGB').save(in_mem_file, format='JPEG')
            img.save(in_mem_file, format='JPEG')
            img_write = storage.open(self.player_img.name, 'w+')
            img_write.write(in_mem_file.getvalue())
            img_write.close()

        img_read.close()
```

Views.py

```
class player_add(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Players
    template_name = 'player_create.html'

    form_class = forms.PlayerForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: wait, why did you wrote `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` at the top of your model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super().save(*args, **kwargs)` should be the last line of code in your `def save(self, *args, **kwargs)` method, not where it is now.